# In my React Native application I cannot check when a user installed the app from a Branch.io link in Android, but shows in the Liveview

Tags: android, react-native, deep-linking, branch.io

I'm adding Branch.io in my react native application and already successfully passed the linking process.

Right now I'm making tests for when a user installs the app simulating the install as the documentation say. For iOS the process works fine, when I click the link the App Store opens then I proceed to close it and install the app via Xcode and when the app opens the "getFirstReferringParams" have the is_first_session field as true, and the dashboard shows that.

The problem is for Android. Following the same process, I get the same answer to the app from the "getFirstReferringParams" but in the dashboard only count one more for the field "clicks" and "opens" but the field "install" remains unchanged, I am unable to know if the app was installed by using this link.

After that, I verified if in the Liveview page (dashboard.branch.io/liveview) and the Events from Android are showing in there, but not are been count it in the Quick Links view (dashboard.branch.io/quick-links) for the field Install.

Any suggestions? Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

It seems like the Branch system recognizes your Android device and for this reason is counting an open instead of an install. Branch will only count one install per app per device. All subsequent install attempts will be marked as an "open". To correct this and continue using your device for testing, you may need to simulate an install on your Android device. Please see the below instructions on how to simulate an install below:

https://docs.branch.io/pages/apps/react-native/#simulate-an-install

Cheers,
Joie - 
Branch Support

Comment: Hi @Joie, in the Liveview the event comes as an Install and in the getFirstReferringParams the object is empty so must be the first time no?, and in iOS trying the same is counting in the dashboard as a new Install , not must be the same result for Android? . If I try with a live link, must show the install event in the dashboard?